# If $E$ is a curve on a surface $X$ with $E^2=0$, then $h^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(E))\geq 2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth rational algebraic surface over $\Bbb{C}$ such that $-K_X$ is effective.

Let $E\subset X$ be a curve such that $E^2=0$.

Is it necessarily true that $h^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(E))\geq 2$?

Here's where I'm at:

By Serre duality $h^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X(E))=h^0(X,K_X-E)=0$, since $E-K_F$ is effective. Since $X$ is rational, $\chi(X)=1$ and by Riemann-Roch, $h^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(E))-h^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X(E))=1-\frac{1}{2}E\cdot K_X$.

Since $-K_X$ is effective and $E^2=0$, then $-E\cdot K_X\geq 0$. If $-E\cdot K_X>0$, then necessarily $h^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(E))\geq 2$.

Now I don't know what to do when $E\cdot K_X=0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true, and the counterexample is in fact the same one as for your previous question: let $S$ be the blowup of $\mathbf P^2$ in 9 general points, and let $C$ be the proper transform of the unique cubic through those 9 points.

Then $C^2=0$ and $h^0(S,C)=1$.

Comment: Thank you again, Lazzaro. But I still have a question: let $C_1$ be a smooth cubic in $\Bbb{P}^2$ and $C_2=L_1+L_2+L_3$, where $L_1,L_2,L_3$ are lines such that $C_1,C_2$ intersect transversely at 9 distinct points. Then $C_1,C_2$ generate a pencil of cubics with 9 base points. If $S\to\Bbb{P}^2$ is the blowup at the 9 points, we obtain an elliptic fibration $S\to \Bbb{P}^1$. Using your notation, if $C$ is the transform of $C_1$, then $K_S=-C$. Since $|-K_S|$ gives the elliptic fibration, shouldn't we have $h^0(S,C)=2$?

Comment: Everything you say is correct, but the set of 9 points in your construction is not general. For 9 general points, there is a unique cubic through them.

Comment: Yes, that's right. One last question: if $X$ is the blowup of 9 points in general position, we will have $K_S=-3L+E_1+...+E_9$, right? In that case $-K_S$ wouldn't be effective

Comment: That is the correct expression for $K_S$. Buti t is not true that $-K_S$ is not effective: just as you said in your first commen, $-K_S=C$ in this case.